# Form Check boxes not coming through

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox

I can not get the form check boxes to come through to the email for "recycling". I do not know php so I have no idea what is wrong. When the form comes through to email the "Recycling:" subject is there, but the checked boxes are not.

HTML:

```
    <label>CRT Monitors <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" value="crtmonitors" 
    /></label>
    <label>Printers <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" value="printers" 
    /></label> 

    <label>Computers  <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" value="computers" 
    /></label>

    <label>Fluorescent Lamps and Batteries <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" 
    value="lamps" /></label> 

    <label>Televisions <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" value="television" 
    /></label> 

    <label>Other Equipment <input name="recycleobject2[]" type="checkbox" value="other" /> 
    </label><br />
```

PHP:

```
    $recycleobject2 = $_POST['recycleobject2']; // not required  
    $recycleobject2 = array();
    $email_message .= "Recycling:" .implode(", ",$recycleobject2)."\n";
```

Comment: Place `$recycleobject2 = array();` before.

Comment: Or just remove it.  Depends on other checks in the code.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is right here:

```
$recycleobject2 = array();
```

That line is resetting the $recycleobject2 variable to a brand new empty array. Remove that line and your code should be fine.

Comment: When I take that out I receive this error, when the boxes are not checked.: 
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/content/g/t/d/gtdcompaq/html/verify.php on line 88

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/g/t/d/gtdcompaq/html/verify.php:88) in /home/content/g/t/d/gtdcompaq/html/verify.php on line 110                                                (Line 88 is:$email_message .= "Recycling:" .implode(", ",$recycleobject2)."\n";)

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['recycleobject2']) && is_array($_POST['recycleobject2']) && count($_POST['recycleobject2']) 
{
$recycleobject2 = $_POST['recycleobject2'];
}
else
$recycleobject2 = array();`